# xcode and swift3 : vertical slider constraints

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, slider, constraints

I have made an application with 10 sliders which i rotate to vertical using:

```
slider1outlet.transform = CGAffineTransform.init( rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2))
```

same for slider 2 thru 10
this works whitout a problem, but i want to add constraints so they go maximum height and are evenly distributed across the width of the screen, and they adapt when i rotate my screen.

this doesn't seem to work, the constraint seems to turn with the slider and i dont want that.

i have made screenshots (with only 3 sliders just for demo purposes)
the first slider has a red background to show what i mean, here is the screenshot of the application whitout rotating the sliders:

[image: no rotation]

with the rotating sliders (only 1st slider has red background):

[image: with rotation]